# What is a good way to do a SUMIF on dictionary values?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, sum

I was wondering what is a nice, elegant pythonic way to run a sumif on values of keys in a dictionary that adhere to a certain condition. For example, this dict:

```
color_codes = {'red':1,'yellow':2, 'green':3, 'brown':4, 'blue':5, 'pink':6, 'black': 7}
```

lets say I want the sum of all the values of the keys, given that the value is >= a certain number x.
How would you go about it? Anonymous function maybe?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `sum()` with generator expression may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
sum(v for v in color_codes.itervalues() if v > x)
```

The argument to `sum` is a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), and the result is the sum of the values that are greater than `x`.

Comment: I want to sum the values. Values of the keys. (2+3+4+...)

Comment: @Optimesh I simplified the answer. The result is the same.

Comment: @juanchopanza I saw. Many thanks. I can only mark it as the correct answer in 7 minutes so I'll do that in a bit. :)